# Write dictionary with rows to csv iterating

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, iteration, writer

I need to write a dictionary to a csv, but the problem is that I can't hold it in the memory, so I have to iterate:

```
def save_phons_2_csv(pandas_dataset, csv_name):
    if not os.path.isfile(csv_name): #create file if it doesn't exists
        with open(csv_name, 'w')as csv_file:
            pass
    for index_r, row in pandas_dataset.iterrows(): #get all phons frames
        for index, phon_dict in enumerate(row['phons']):
            if (phon_dict['phon'] not in no_phons):
                dicc = get_phonema(row, index)
                label = dicc['label']
                rows = np.array(dicc["frames"])

                with open(csv_name,'a+') as ofile:               
                    ... append label and rows to csv
```

In the end, what I want to do is store `label` and `rows` in a csv file and be able to read it back.

My best attempt so far is this:

```
            with open(csv_name,'a+') as ofile:               
                wr = csv.writer(ofile)
                wr.writerow([label, rows])
```

but it writes some of them skippping most of the frames, like this:

```
sh,"[array([ 0.0005188 ,  0.        ,  0.00036621, ..., -0.00024414,
       -0.00131226, -0.0015564 ], dtype=float32)]"

ix,"[array([-0.0015564 , -0.00131226, -0.00061035, ...,  0.0017395 ,
        0.00012207, -0.00164795], dtype=float32)]"
```

Also it puts a `\n` wherever it wants.

EDIT: Acclarations:

label is a string, like 'sh' or 'ix' or something like that

rows is an array like [ 0.0005188   0.          0.00036621 ..., -0.00024414 -0.00131226 -0.0015564 ]

I also have the maximun length of all frames in case it helps

This is what I get if I do `print(pandas_dataset.head())`:

```
 Dialect  Female    ID   Male Type  \
0     DR1    True  CJF0  False   SA   
1     DR1    True  CJF0  False   SA   
2     DR1    True  CJF0  False   SI   
3     DR1    True  CJF0  False   SI   
4     DR1    True  CJF0  False   SI   

                                                path  \
0  C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\Database\TIMIT\TRAI...   
1  C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\Database\TIMIT\TRAI...   
2  C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\Database\TIMIT\TRAI...   
3  C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\Database\TIMIT\TRAI...   
4  C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\Database\TIMIT\TRAI...   

                                               phons  \
0  [{'end': 3050, 'start': 0, 'phon': 'h#'}, {'en...   
1  [{'end': 2260, 'start': 0, 'phon': 'h#'}, {'en...   
2  [{'end': 1513, 'start': 0, 'phon': 'h#'}, {'en...   
3  [{'end': 2120, 'start': 0, 'phon': 'h#'}, {'en...   
4  [{'end': 1507, 'start': 0, 'phon': 'h#'}, {'en...   

                                               words  
0  [{'end': 5723, 'start': 3050, 'word': 'she'}, ...  
1  [{'end': 4600, 'start': 2260, 'word': 'don't'}...  
2  [{'end': 7436, 'start': 1513, 'word': 'even'},...  
3  [{'end': 3533, 'start': 2120, 'word': 'or'}, {...  
4  [{'end': 2154, 'start': 1507, 'word': 'a'}, {'...
```

Comment: Don't you need to iterate the rows? `for row in rows: wr.writerow([label, rows])`

Comment: csv cannot handle array data-type row, so it converts the array to string and hence the loss of all the data. You can either save it as writerow([label]+rows), but looks like u writing columns here ?

Comment: That prints something like I got but many times each phonema @PeterWood

Comment: @pratiklodha Actually I'm trying to write it as rows, but it would be ok to write it as columns as long as I could read it back. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: It would help if you could add the output of `print(pandas_dataset.head())` to the question and also what your expected output should look like for that data.

Comment: @MartinEvans Added output of `print(pandas_dataset.head())`. With respect to the output I don't care about the format as long as I can read it back.

Comment: If all you want to do is to write/read the dataframe then you can start with [`pandas_dataset.to_csv('output.csv')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) and [`pandas.read_csv('output.csv')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) to read it back.

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes, but pandas_dataset doesn't contains the info that I want to store. I have to process it before by calling `get_phonema(row, index)` and also I cannot process it all at once because that will be tons of GBs

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to save it to a csv, but I don't think it is a good solution so I will leave this answer unmarked in case someone came up with a better one.

```
def save_phons_2_csv(pandas_dataset, csv_name):
    np.set_printoptions(threshold = np.inf, linewidth = np.inf)
    if not os.path.isfile(csv_name): #create file if it doesn't exists
        with open(csv_name, 'w')as csv_file:
            pass

    for index_r, row in pandas_dataset.iterrows(): #get all phons frames
        for index, phon_dict in enumerate(row['phons']):
            if (phon_dict['phon'] not in no_phons):
                dicc = get_phonema(row, index)
                label = dicc['label']
                rows = dicc["frames"]
                with open(csv_name,'a+') as ofile: 
                    text = '%s; %s\n' % (label, rows)
                    ofile.write(text)
```

Basically what I did is seting up how np prints the output.

This gave me a csv like this:

```
sh   [ -3.35693359e-04   3.35693359e-04  -6.71386719e-04   9.46044922e-04...
iy   [  4.94384766e-03  -1.58691406e-03   7.93457031e-04   8.85009766e-04...
...
```

There are two cells per row, one for the label and one for the frames, it would be better to have one cell for each frame I think

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to improve matters by using a CSV writer object:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv


def save_phons_2_csv(pandas_dataset, csv_name):
    np.set_printoptions(threshold = np.inf, linewidth = np.inf)
    if not os.path.isfile(csv_name): #create file if it doesn't exists
        with open(csv_name, 'w')as csv_file:
            pass

    with open(csv_name, 'a+', newline='') as ofile:             
        csv_ofile = csv.writer(ofile)

        for index_r, row in pandas_dataset.iterrows(): #get all phons frames
            for index, phon_dict in enumerate(row['phons']):
                if phon_dict['phon'] not in no_phons:
                    dicc = get_phonema(row, index)
                    label = dicc['label']
                    rows = dicc["frames"]
                    csv_ofile.writerow([label] + list(rows))
```

This takes a list of elements and writes a line to your output file with the correct delimiters between each element.